# VSCode Julia : "quiet" Editing

Tags: julia, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

under Windows 10 *{VSC 1.61.0 with Julia v1.4.3 Extension [julialang,
Julia Language Support]}* there seems to be no setting to '**shut-the-editor-up**', make it **work silent**, just as like a TextEditor w/out any pop-up or pop-in or blending-in of anything whatsoever.

hovering over a variable, for instance, lets the VSC-Editor provide additional info, reference etc.

not even the Zen mode can be configured in such a manner that the VSC-Editor keeps totally quiet -- i'd like just the colour scheme working, nothing else needed.

Sublime Text 4 as editor works well, more to my taste but i'd prefer not to use it in a specific setting, on a laptop.
i'd just like to **edit** code **lines** **w/out** any '**interference**' in VSC that keeps whatever colour-scheme intact.

is there a setting i might have overlooked ?

everything *sense-wise in Prefs/Settings i checked in order to silence the VSC-Editor -- no success, so far

***Thanks in advance for Your suggestion(s) !***

Comment: I'd recommend uninstalling the Julia extension if you don't want any of its features, since Julia syntax highlighting ships with VS Code nowadays.

Comment: I'm not certain, but "things pop up when I don't want them to" is a common complaint about the IntelliSense feature/problem (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense). You can try to customize that in `settings.json`, the link has more details. Hovering actions are customizable with the `editor.hover.` fields.

Comment: thanks, BatWannaBe. will look into that. perhaps i did overlook a switch, whatever ..

Comment: you can disable parameterHints as shown here: http://blog.shawnhyde.com/post/2019/02/16/how-to-disable-popup-tips-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: thanks Bill. parameterHints etc switched off are a relief !